# Search patterns from the text file and if pattern missing place a value Null

Tags: python-3.6

Esteemed colleagues, I have a raw data format as i detailed below where primarily it has to be three line and every line is starts with pattern `dn:` following `ftpuser` and `description`, whereas there are situations where the third line `description` is missing hence First two lines are intacted in this case. Now, I'm using a multiline regex to match all these patterns and using it to get the data from my `data` variable and this is passed to the regex(re.findall), Further, i have for looped the `matchObj` to get the values in a index form so i have can only the desired indexes from `new_str` List.

> Below is the  Data File :

```
dn: uid=ac002,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y
description: file transfer|12/31/2010|file transfer

dn: uid=ab02,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: disabled_5Mar07
description: Remedy Tkt 01239399 regg move

dn: uid=mela,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y
description: ROYALS|none|customer account

dn: uid=aa01,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: T

dn: uid=aa02,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y

dn: uid=aa03,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y

dn: uid=bb01,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: T

dn: uid=bb02,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y

dn: uid=bb03,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y

dn: uid=bb05,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y

dn: uid=ab01,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: Y
description:: VGVzdGluZyA=

dn: uid=tt@regg.com,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpuser: T
description: REG-JP|7-31-05|REG-JP
```

Below is the code which i tried, but the problem here is as , this code only picks the data where it gets all three lines (`dn:`,`ftpuser`,`description`) and line where it has only two lines ((`dn:`,`ftpuser`) it fails to retrieve those hence i would like to know , how we can get those line also into the similar output making/appending `Description: null` wherever its missing

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# ./dataparse.py
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
import re
with open('test2', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        data = f.read()
        regex = (r"dn:(.*?)\nftpuser: (.*)\ndescription:* (.*)")
        matchObj = re.findall(regex, data)
        for index in matchObj:
            #print(index)
            index_str = ' '.join(index)
            new_str = re.sub(r'[=,]', ' ', index_str)
            new_str = new_str.split()
            print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}".format(new_str[1],new_str[8],new_str[9]))
```

> Resulted output:

```
$ ./dataparse.py
ab02                          disabled_5Mar07     Remedy
mela                          Y                   ROYALS|none|customer
ab01                          Y                   VGVzdGluZyA
tt@regg.com                   T                   REG-JP|7-31-05|REG-JP
```

As a python beginner i would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make description optional in your regex pattern. Change it to:

```
r"dn:(.*?)\nftpuser: (.*)\n(?:description:* (.*))?"
```

Comment: blhsing, this looks good but when i ran it , it  throws `IndexError: list index out of range` which looks to be because certain lines dont have index[9].

Comment: Yes because now there's no description for some of the matches, and you're using some string manipulations and a `split` to obtain `new_str`, which causes the last item to be missing if there's no description. You should just use `index.group(3)` for description, instead of `new_str[9]`.

Comment: Would be able to state that change in the line statement .

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. State what change?

Comment: apologies for inconvinience , i mean cang i should do here in below Print in place of `new_str[9]`statement ..

`print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}".format(new_str[1],new_str[8],new_str[9]))`

Comment: Like I said above, use `index.group(3)` instead of `new_str[9]`. So `print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}".format(new_str[1],new_str[8],index.group(3)))`.

Comment: that does not work ..`    print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}".format(new_str[1],new_str[8],index.group(3)))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'group'
`

Comment: I see. I thought `index` is a `match` object. In this case it is a `tuple`, so change `new_str[9]` to `index[2]` instead.

Comment: yes, findall() returns the matches as a list... in the event of groups, it returns it as a list of tuples.